# mocha testing beforeEach inside a loop - asynchronous issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, loopbackjs

So, I'm running some tests on my node.js app.

The test iterates through all my models and checks each model's exposed api. The `it` calls check only the public models, depending on the model's `public` property.

Before the `it` calls are made, I want to pass some test data to the models using `beforeEach` at each iteration. Unfortunately, due to asynchronous calls (I'm guessing), the the iterator value in `beforeEach` remains the same. I'm guessing the loop is executed even before `beforeEach`. I have two `it` calls per model resulting in `beforeEach` being called twice per model.

---

UPDATE

I guess I'll have to show my entire use case cause this is a little more complicated than what I've asked here. Cody's solution seems possible, but it still doesn't help my use case. This is because I have a few conditions in the loop which runs the test only for certain models and not all. Also, there are two `it` calls, meaning `beforeEach` is called twice for every iteration of the loop. Here's the code:

```
var models = {'Ate': {'property1': 'prop'}, 'Bat': {'property2': 'prop2'}, 'Cat': {'property3': 'prop3'}};
var modelConfigs = {'Ate': {'public': 'true'}, 'Bat': {'public': 'false'}, 'Cat': {'public': 'true'}};

describe('Given an array of model objects', function(){

    for(var key in modelConfigs) {

        var m = key;
        var modelConfig = modelConfigs[m];
        var model = models[m].definition;
        var modelPlural = models[m].settings.plural;

        if(modelConfig.public) { // Condition runs for only some models     
            beforeEach(function (done) {
               var test = this;
               var testKey = m;
               console.log(testKey); //Output is always Cat.
               done();
            });

            lt.describe.whenCalledRemotely('GET', '/api/' + modelPlural, function() {
                it('should have status code 200', function() { //First it call
                    assert.equal(this.res.statusCode, 200);
                });
                it('should be sorted DESC by date', function() { //Second it call
                    var modelRes = this.res.body;

                    expect(modelRes).to.be.instanceOf(Array);
                    expect(modelRes).to.have.length.below(11);
                    console.log(modelRes.length);

                    if(modelRes.length > 0) {
                        for(var i=1; i< modelRes.length; i++) {
                            expect(modelRes[i-1]['date']).to.be.at.least(modelRes[i]['date']);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });    
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are we supposed to assume app.models looks like `[{'a':'a'},{'b':'b'},{'c':'c'}]` or like `{'a': 'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c'}`? Because `{{'a':'a'},{'b':'b'},{'c':'c'}}` is not a valid javascript object. Beyond that, your for statement has a typo in it, should read `for (var key in models) {` instead.

Comment: I typed that out in a hurry, so made some typos. I guess the code is just representational. I've made edits now :)

Comment: No problem, it's just always best to correct minor typos like that when they get noticed as it helps people answer the question. I've posted a 'working' solution below, but it's certainly not the cleanest solution in the world. It basically breaks up the for loop into the before/beforeEach functions.

Comment: Are you doing other things in your beforeEach function here? Because, as written, you're defining x `beforeEach` functions, where x is the number of models, and that's obviously not what you want to be doing I would assume. I think you still need to post more information to get more specific help, but take a look at the question and answers Louis linked above, it might help.

Comment: It was indeed an issue with closures! Thanks Louis. I used forEach to fix the problem. Everything's working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, though I'm sure there's a cleaner solution available:

```
var models = {'a': 'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c'}
var modelsArray = []
for(var key in models) {
  modelsArray.push(key)
}
describe("Given models", function () {
  var currModel, index, testKey, test
  before(function() {
    index = 0;
  })
  beforeEach(function() {
    test = this;
    testKey = modelsArray[index]
    currModel = models[testKey]
    index++
  })
  for(var i = 0; i < modelsArray.length; i++) {
    it("Does whatever you need to test", function() {
      console.log(testKey)
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey Cody, please take a look at my update, maybe that'll give you better insight into what my problem actually is. Your solution works for the question I had asked, but my use case is a little more complicated. Have edited the question accordingly. Thanks!